# create adatabase through CreateDatabaseDocument() function

Tags: database, c#-4.0, nosql, ravendb

I want to create a database in ravendb , I used EnsureDatabaseExist() function. I am not able to use the function CreateDatabaseDocument() from namespace Raven.Client.Extensions and class is public static class MultiDatabase{} in my c# code. Intellisense in vs2010 not showing this function.

my code is :`enter code here`

```
 public CreateDatabaseOpResult CreateDatabase(ConnectionOperationResult connection,string name)
        {
            DocumentDatabase database;
            CreateDatabaseOpResult databaseOperationResult = new CreateDatabaseOpResult();
            if (connection.IsOperationSuccessfull == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var doc = connection.documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDefaultDatabase();
                    var docId = doc.Get("Raven/Databases/" + name);
                    if (docId == null)
                    {
                        //static class
                        //multidatabase
                        connection.documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        databaseOperationResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = false;
                        throw new ArgumentException("Database already exists");
                    }
                    databaseOperationResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = true;
                    databaseOperationResult.database = database;
                }


//and i want to use this function from

namespace Raven.Client.Extensions
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Methods to create mutli tenants databases
    ///</summary>
    public static class MultiDatabase
    {
        public static RavenJObject CreateDatabaseDocument(string name)
        {
            AssertValidName(name);
            var doc = RavenJObject.FromObject(new DatabaseDocument
            {
            Settings =      
                               {
                                 {"Raven/DataDir", Path.Combine("~", Path.Combine("Tenants", name))}
                               }
                    });
        doc.Remove("Id");
              return doc;
    }


thanks in advance...:)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateDatabase` is an internal method which just returned the database **document**. `EnsureDatabaseExist` used this method and also stores that document if it doesn't exists.

You should use `EnsureDatabaseExist` method.

Comment: thank you so much ..
But How can I get database object from this function.Because further I need to work on this database object...

Comment: Call EnsureDatabaseExists, then get the document from the server, modify it, and save.

Comment: It is giving exception "Unable to load one or more of the requested types."
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(name);
                databaseOperationResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = true;
                Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration memoryRaven = new Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration()
                {
                    DatabaseName = name,
                };
                DocumentDatabase database = new DocumentDatabase(memoryRaven);

//In last statement it throws an exception.please help me

Comment: You're calling `EnsureDatabaseExists` before the database is running.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are trying to load RavenDB with missing dlls. In your configuration, make sure you are referencing Raven.Storage.Managed.dll

Comment: thanks mr. oren i was missing lucene.net dll now it is giving me null reference exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for object of DocumentDatabase object..will you please tell me how to instantiate this object..thanks a ton in advance. :) sorry for my lack of understanding

Comment: DocumentDatabase database = new DocumentDatabase(memoryRaven); in this line the exception occurs